# как связать 2 checkbox в Microsoft Word?

Tags: checkbox, ms-word

Есть два чекбокса, как можно сделать, чтобы при нажатии на один, второй тоже помечался крестиком и наоборот? То есть связать их вместе и при этом чтобы они могли находиться в разных частях документа?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Чекбоксы в ворде? Это что-то новенькое...

Comment: @Anamnian Старенькое на самом деле. Давно уже есть, с 2007 версии, кажется.

Comment: Каждому написать обработчик события Change, который установит значение другого чекбокса. И флаг, исключающий зацикливание.